# How can I force a component update with non-component class objects?

Tags: reactjs

I have a React component with a non-component class object in its state. Right now, I am using the React component to display some of the other object's fields. I also want to make it so that every time the displayed field in the non-component class object changes, the react component is re-rendered to show that new updated field. How can I do this?

```
class ReactComponentClass extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            myObj: new SimpleJSClass()
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <p>Value: {this.state.myObj.value}</p>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

class SimpleJSClass {
    constructor() {
        this.value = 1
    }
}
```

I have heard of `this.forceUpdate()` but is that the only option? If it is possible, I would like to only update `value` instead of everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In React a component rerenders when its state changes. React will notice the change if the this.setState method is called.

You can create a class variable with the new instance

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.simpleClassInstance = new SimpleJSClass();
  this.state = {
    myObj: this.simpleClassInstance
  }
}
```

So when the class content upgraded call a setState with it.

```
this.setState({myObj: this.simpleClassInstance})
```

On the other hand I rarely use classes for data. I always use objects. Mutating the state is considered harmful. So calling setState with a new object when a data is changed is the common solution.